# Vernam Cipher shared secret key

Tags: cryptography, xor, secret-key

A and B share the secret key K. 
They agree the following protocol for the instigator of communication between them to authenticate the receiver when communicating over an insecure channel. The instigator encrypts a random number, R, the same length as the key by XORing it with the shared secret key. They then send the result to the other party.The receiver, decrypts the message by XORing it with their secret key and returns the result to the sender.

1. If A initiates communication with B and sends 11FF, in hexadecimal, and B replies 830A, determine the hexadecimal value of the secret key shared by A and B.

I tried solving this problem by xor-ing the binary equivalence of 11FF and 830A but i dont think im getting the correct anwser

Answer (score 0):

K_A = K_B = shared secret

R = secret Random Number choosen by A

M_A = R XOR K_A = 0x11ff

M_B = M_A XOR K_B = 0x830a = R XOR K_A XOR K_B = R

K_A = K_B = M_A XOR R = 0x11ff XOR 0x830a = 0x92f5 = no longer a secret